# Missing best bet from keywords defined in seperate web application

Tags: 2010, search

I have my search center located at portal.domain/searchcenter and "Search Keywords" I have defined at portal.domain show up in my search center results.  However, all search keywords I have set up at team.domain will not show up when I search (no matter where I search from).

Search is configured to index team.domain, and results from the content hosted there show up in results, just not my keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search is not my strong point but I believe that Best Bets/Keywords are limited to the site collection hosting your search center.  That is, you will need to define all keywords/Best bets in "portal.domain"